# How to use PostCSS in angular cli

Tags: angular, postcss

I'm starting a new project with angular 4, and I want to integrate with PostCss for use modules such as: Autoprefixer, CSSNext and another modules.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1512#issuecomment-254262959
But I need say what I don't used it before.

And if you don't use CLI, then may try set options in webpack config for build css code from scss, for example. Just use require() for your styling file. Read more here (in notice block) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#style-urls-in-metadata

Answer (score 0):

I just released [postcss-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-angular), a custom postcss syntax extracting styles within Angular components. Especially useful for integrating Stylelint into your codebase.